# What is a sensible structure for multiple-language project in source control?

Tags: version-control, projects-and-solutions, monorepo

At work we're developing a large-scale application with quite a few front-end, back-end and support components. Typically the front-end is developed in C# and the back-end is developed in Java, although parts of the back-end are also developed in C# and possibly later C++.

The choice of language and platform is not arbitrary; we try to weigh the relative merits of each in development time, tool-chain cost, familiarity with the language by the specific development team etc. What all these components have in common, though, is that they are all required for the complete operation of the product, and that they are being developed concurrently by independent (but highly communicative) teams.

Previously, we have used Team Foundation Server for our .NET code and Subversion for our Java code; because there was clear separation of the teams' responsibilities, this caused little problem beyond the inconvenience of placing binaries (WARs, in this case) generated from one source tree in another, and the high manual overhead of keeping the branches and revisions in sync. With this project, the degree of separation between the teams is intentionally much smaller, and the volume of branching/merging is expected to be considerably higher; as a result we're moving to a unified VCS, more specifically Subversion.

This brings me to the meat of the question: how does one mix Java and C# code effectively? In practice, we'll have .NET code dependent on a Java codebase; the Java binaries are required to run anything other than unit test code (integration tests already require the binaries, and QA, acceptance testing etc. certainly does as well). What we currently have in mind looks something like:

```
/trunk
    /java
        /component1
        /component2
        /library1
        /library2
    /net
        /assembly1
        /assembly2
        /...
        project.sln
```

The idea is that the entire source tree is placed under one branch; the .NET code is dependant on the Java code, so we'll add a post-build step to the solution which will (most likely) call the ant script for the Java components. This allows branching of the entire codebase (for .NET developers) or just the Java components (for Java developers).

The problems with this solution are:

1. What happens when one of the two codebases becomes so large that making copies of it for every branch gets impractical? (our thoughts: split to separate repositories for .NET and Java code and use svn:externals, any input on this would be *greatly* appreciated).
2. We use Eclipse for Java development. How do we manage the "shared" workspace (i.e. which projects are required for which components, the dependency graph etc.)? Up until now we've had relatively few Java components, so each developer could just keep all of them in the workspace at the same time. With the increase in Java components and Java developers I don't see how we can keep doing that; any suggestions on how to keep the workspace versioned (a la solution files) while still maintaining sync between the two code-bases?

I would love to hear your input!

Comment: We eventually went with the solution described above. Branch creation/checkout time is indeed long, but not horribly so (since we moved to a much thinner branching model). Since we haven't found a decent alternative, this is the structure I would recommend for similar teams.

Answer (score 2):

1: I've found it best to group things by component, rather than langugage. If one component requires several languages for interface, you still need to develop, test and release them as one. So, splitting a component across several repos is *not* a good idea.

If one part of the code depends tightly on the other, keep it together. Better to split components across repos. (This even goes for internal structure, where, especially as things grow, it's difficult if you package things by type, rather than by function, i.e. in MVC, don't have three huge packages for each category, rather keep FooView, FooModel and FooController tight.)

svn:externals might work, and with the later versions I think you can use "internals", i.e. link to other dirs in the same repo. That is miles easier than managing separate repos, especially with tagging and branching. (shudder)

2: You could always have the developers setup different workspaces, or perhaps use working sets. Commercial Eclipse releases has better support for sharing workspace settings than the OS variant. (Haven't tried, only worked and been frustrated with the OS one)

I've done C++ (MSVS) and Java (Eclipse) in one repo, and it works pretty well. Also C++/Python similarly. Make sure your build system supports building and testing everything (even if your IDEs only build one part).

Comment: Our components are typically made up of only one language; a server component is written in Java and hosted in Tomcat. Normally we have a thin client layer written in .NET to interface with it, and which hardly ever changes, but I'll definitely bring your suggestion to the table, thanks!
2. I'll try and have a look at the commercial variants, then, though if that's the direction we go we'll probably consider IDEA much more seriously.

Thanks again!

Comment: Ok. I'd then keep the client layer in the same repo as the server code, but the client "app" code could be separate. Nice to know it was helpful. :)