# If monorepo should contains only one language projects?

Tags: javascript, php, monorepo

I'm wondering... Should monorepo contains projects written in the same language? I consider to push my front-end and PHP projects to monorepo to share JSON configs between them.

Is it worth to do that or projects written in specific language should be placed in different monorepo?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808052/what-is-a-sensible-structure-for-multiple-language-project-in-source-control

Answer (score 2):

#### On using a mono-repo

Regarding a mono-repo.  I feel that they should be limited to deployable units and/or connected libraries.  If all of the projects in a mono-repo will be deployed together, sure.  If they're all extensions to a single library/framework, sure.  Otherwise, break them up as you see fit.

#### Sharing configurations

As for sharing configuration details (JSON), I prefer a separate project *JUST* for configuration details (see `@tracker1/config-merge` in npm).  As part of my Release pipeline, I'll output the latest into the distribution as part of the release bundling.  It makes it easier for me.  Other options would be to have it cloned on-demand, or otherwise pulled in.

It's worth noting that the module above is only part of my configuration projects, I also add templates to my output, then use transforms as part of release/deployment.

#### Multiple languages

As to multiple languages, use what you need to.  Other than in the JS community, I rarely see projects that only use one language/tool.  Often even it's `make` scripts, even then there's generally `bash`, `cmd.exe` or `powershell` as part of a build pipeline.

These days, I often just lean towards having node scripts as my secondary tooling regardless of the primary language.  It's too easy to `npm init` and use `shelljs` to create cross-platform scripts that work anywhere I need them to (windows, linux, macos).

---

For reference, I use the following to call external processes from my node scripts...

```
const exec = (command, args = []) => {
  const { status } = cp.spawnSync(command, args, { stdio: 'inherit' });

  if (status) {
    const cmd = `${command} ${args.map(a => `"${a}"`).join(' ')}`;
    console.error(`\n\nSTATUS ${status} on: ${cmd}`);
    process.exit(status);
  }
};
```